# "Alligator pear" and "sparrow grass" for "avocado" and "asparagus"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Do "sparrow grass" and "alligator pear" have any currency in spoken AE, or are these terms chiefly dialectal?

Comment: Both terms are simply approximate alliterations of the "proper" names. Since it's inconceivable any significant number of retail chains would use them, it's highly unlikely many people would be unaware of the standard terms, therefore it's just POB as to whether they use the alternatives facetiously or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Alligator pear is more of a description of the appearance than a mere alliterative.

Comment: That partly depends on which particular variety you're thinking of. In the UK we see more of the green smooth-skinned types than the brownish/black knobbly ones. But I honestly think it's *way* ott to say the descriptive element is *more* relevant than the alliterative one. It seems to me if it didn't have the same number of (similar) syllables, there's virtually no chance ***alligator*** would be used in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was dumbfounded by this comment about similar syllables. Then I realized this was one of those *two countries separated by a common language* moments. In AmE alligator and avocado sound nothing alike.  To the point where my mind was set agog by the suggestion!!!!

Comment: @DavidM: [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=avocado) says that *alligator pear* originated from confusion of the Spanish words (I assume by Englishmen who did not speak much Spanish) *alvacata* and  *alligato*.

Comment: @PeterShor As far as my knowledge of Spanish (and better my dictionary's knowledge) alvacata isn't a word. The Spanish words for avocado and alligator are *aguacate* and *aligátor* respectively.   I can perhaps understand the confusion on those fronts. But, a Hass avocado and other cultivars look like an alligator's skin and has the shape of a pear. [Wikipedia - the world's least impeachable source ;-) agrees with me.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado)

Comment: @DavidM: from the [Stanford Dictionary of Anglicized Words and Phrases](http://books.google.com/books?id=0KAYAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA122&dq=alvacata&hl=en&sa=X&ei=35gTU_7BKoLk0wG-qIGgCQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=alvacata&f=false), via Google books: *The form **alvacata** may be fr. an earlier Sp. rendering of the native name, and perhaps accounts for the English corruption **alligator***.

Comment: @Peter That I can accept.

Comment: And *etymonline* clearly misspelled *aligato* … there couldn't have been a double l there, because that has a different pronunciation in Spanish (*aligato* I can believe, because [*alligator*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=alligator&searchmode=none) came from  the Spanish *el lagarto de Indias*, or *the lizard of the Indies*).

Comment: @petershor I think you will allow that there is a fair bit of synergism here, though. It's easy to mistake something for the word alligator if it also happens to look like one …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard Alton Brown and others use the term *alligator pear* to describe an avocado.  But, it was an attempt to sound campy rather than common usage.

I don't think anyone unfamiliar with this rare usage would immediately know your meaning at first blush.

As to *sparrow grass*… this is the first I've heard it. It is probably a folksy mispronunciation of Asparagus. Similar to *old-timer's disease* in place of *Alzheimer's Disease*.

Purely coincidentally, the word *avocado* comes to English by way of Spanish through serial mispronunciation. Derived from the term aguacate (avocado tree).  This was itself a mispronunciation of the Nahuatl word āhuacatl (meaning testicle).  Many incorrectly assume it comes from abogado which means lawyer (not only because of the similar pronunciation, but also due to the similar meanings of lawyer and testicle).  Source [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado)

Comment: "Sparrow grass" is indeed a mispronunciation of asparagus. It's attested to since the 18th century at least. In 1791, John Walker wrote about the term: "*sparrow-grass* is so general that *asparagus* has an air of stiffness and pedantry." ([source](http://www.ourgrandmotherskitchens.com/?tag=sparrow-grass))

Comment: The term Alligator pear is also used to refer to chayote or mirleton: http://fatfreevegan.com/blog/2010/03/23/louisiana-stuffed-mirletons-chayote/

Comment: From great words [little eggcorns](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/) grow. And flourish, or don't.

Comment: @John: I suppose there might really have been an original "eggcorn" that genuinely was used to mean the seed/fruit of an oak tree - but even if it did ever exist, that one obviously fell on stony ground. Or perhaps it just survived long enough to give birth to its mutant offspring, which definitely flourishes today. Partly thanks to the Internet, I suspect, which allows a constant stream of new coinages to be publicised, even if they don't actually have any true "parentage" in past non-facetious usage.

Comment: Right. It's more like DNA sharing between bacteria, or occasionally polyploidy.